# Symfony api platform ignore jwt token

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, doctrine, lexikjwtauthbundle

Iam creating symfony api (api platform) with jwt (LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle)

Login works great. I added this into security.yaml

```
login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```

Server return me token. But when I create secure source like

```
- { path: ^/api/notes, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

And send request with token with authorization like

```
Bearer --token--
```

Server ignore it and return
"Full authentication is required to access this resource."

How can i recognize whats wrong? I spent 5 hours with it, but I dont know, what I can do.

I Run server with symfony server:start

When I created test controller like

```
 #[Route('/test', name: 'test')]
public function index(Request $request): Response
{
    $auth = $request->headers->get("Authorization");
    return new Response("Authorization: ". "'".$auth."'");
}
```

It works, server print me token

```
Authorization: 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJh.....'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing some configuration. You only configured the json_login options, so that the Lexik bundle is now responsible for handling the logging in of your users and issuing JWTs. By default, API platform will still authenticate requests based on session-based cookies, not through the Authorization header. You have to tell API Platform to authenticate requests based on your JWTs.

I believe that it should be enough to add this to your `security.yml`, but I haven't checked this:

```php
firewalls:
    main:
        stateless: true
        provider: app_user_provider <-- this has to point to your user provider
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        jwt: ~
```

(drop the `pattern`, change `login` to `json_login` and add `jwt: ~`)

Have a look at this documentation: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/ where it shows how to secure the API platform with JWTs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue API Platform by Sylius and a second GraphQL API `/api/v2/graphql` (in addition to the Api platform REST API `/api/v2`).

In the Symfony profiler the security section was disabled for graphQL requests.

The graphql endpoint needs its own firewall :

In `security.yaml`

```
security:
    firewalls:
        graphql_shop_user:
            pattern: "%sylius.security.new_api_route%/graphql"
            provider: sylius_api_shop_user_provider
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```